# C struct to complete assembly code for function

Tags: c, assembly, struct, reverse-engineering

I was given the following code skeleton:

```
typedef struct node {
    _______________ x;
    _______________ y;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node_t;

node_t n;
void func() {
    node_t *m;
    m = ______________________;
    m->y /= 16;
    return; 
}
```

with the following assembly code generated on an IA-32 linux machine:

```
func:
  pushl %ebp
  movl n+12,%eax
  movl 16(%eax),%eax
  movl %esp,%ebp
  movl %ebp,%esp
  shrw $4,8(%eax)
  popl %ebp
  ret
```

And I need to fill in the blanks above.  I do believe that when I look at he lines:

```
m->y /= 16; and shrw $4,8(%eax)
```

this is obviously a right shift on the 8th byte of the node_t *m.  So what I think is that there are 8 bytes before y so x is 8 bytes long (double).  Also, I think that the total size of the struct 'node' comes from the line

```
movl n+12, %eax
```

because that's where the node_t *m is created.   I'm just not sure how to determine the size of this from that line.

I was also give this information

[image]

It should also be noted that pointers are 4 bytes in size and alignment.

Comment: `shrw $4, 8(%eax)` suggests that `m->y` is an `unsigned short`. a signed value would typically use `sar` (shift arithmetic right).

Comment: @BrettHale is that because it's a w after words? Meaning two bytes?

Comment: @scottybobby - you got it. `b`, `w`, `l`, `q` for 1, 2, 4, 8 bytes.

Comment: The table you were given doesn't include a size and alignment for pointers (such as struct node *).

Comment: @rcgldr pointers are 4 bytes and their alignment will be the same

Comment: @rcgldr thanks for pointing that out. I edited the question to show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 32-bit mode, a pointer is 4 bytes, and typically aligned on a 4-byte boundary. So `n + 12` is actually loading `& n.next` to `%eax`. e.g., if `y` *is* an `unsigned short`, there are 2 bytes of padding in the structure before `next`.

`movl 16(%eax),%eax` is dereferencing with a 16-byte offset, to give: `m = n.next->prev`

---

```
struct node
{
    double x;          /* bytes: 0  .. 7  */
    unsigned short y;  /* bytes: 8  .. 9  */
                       /* bytes: 10 .. 11 */ /* (padding) */
    struct node *next; /* bytes: 12 .. 15 */
    struct node *prev; /* bytes: 16 .. 19 */
};
```

Comment: n+12 means that they jumping 12 Bytes from n? So x and y are together 12 Bytes long, correct?

Comment: @T.C. - spot on. `x` could also have been a 64-bit `[unsigned] long long` (or just `long` on LP64 platforms), but that's not given as an option here. The `node` struct is 20 bytes in total.

Comment: pointer of next -> 4Bytes, pointer of prev -> 4Bytes, and the rest? how is that 12 bytes shared? how would you fill the types of the variables x and y?

Comment: @BrettHale I'm not entirely sure how you got m = n.next->prev.  I can't figure out how you counted the 16 bytes while dereferencing.

Comment: @scottybobby - `movl (%eax), %eax` would have 'loaded' the first 4 bytes of the node *pointed to* by `n.next`. The 16 byte offset loads the 4 bytes starting at the 16th byte, i.e., `n.next->prev`.